# Get meta data info for resizing videos

Tags: android, exoplayer

I'm streaming video on a TextureView using Exoplayer.

I need to get the video's width, height and rotation to maintain the aspect ratio.

For that i'm using a [FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever).

The thing is it takes quite a lot of time to retrieve the meta data, since the datasource is an URL.

Any alternative faster solution?

Answer (score 8):

Found the solution. Answering my own question so that it may help someone coming here.

The solution was to implement the methods of `SimpleExoPlayer.VideoListener`

In the `onVideoSizeChanged()` method, you will get the width,height and rotation. You can then manipulate these values and apply the transformation to your TextureView.

```
@Override
public void onVideoSizeChanged(int width, int height, int unappliedRotationDegrees, float pixelWidthHeightRatio) 
{ 
    // do your resizing stuff
}
```

Also, don't forget to add the listener:

```
player.addVideoListener(this);
```

Comment: can u tell me how to get quality of hsl videos like 240p,360p,720p and so on?

Answer (score 1):

use this code to get video width and height after initialize exoPlayer

```
int width;
int height;
int rotationDegrees;
if (exoPlayer.getVideoFormat() != null) {
        Format videoFormat = exoPlayer.getVideoFormat();
        width = videoFormat.width;
        height = videoFormat.height;
        rotationDegrees = videoFormat.rotationDegrees;
        // Switch the width/height if video was taken in portrait mode
        if (rotationDegrees == 90 || rotationDegrees == 270) {
          width = exoPlayer.getVideoFormat().height;
          height = exoPlayer.getVideoFormat().width;
        }
        
      }
```